Negotiating tenure track position after major career grant
I have been pushing hard for several years to get an academic job, with little success. The best job I could get was a non-tenure track group leader position, with very questionable promotion criteria.
Recently, to my own surprise, I managed to win an ERC Starting grant. I am also shortlisted for another grant of equal magnitude. Lucky me, my university has a policy to offer tenure-track positions for ERC grantees.
However, I am somewhat bothered by the fact that the department recently hired a tenure track professor with similar profile to mine, that is to say before the ERC, who received a substantial starting package. Meanwhile they expect me to pay my salary from the grant that I brought in and no starting package.
While I am happy that I will be promoted and it was my dream, I also feel I have done a lot to gain this major grant, so I would like them to match the conditions of the other candidate.
Has anyone had similar experience with this? What could be a good way to proceed?

Generally a start-up package is a negotiation move to attract someone to come to you and not go elsewhere. Will you leave and go somewhere else if you aren't given a matching package?

That’s difficult to say. I am thankful to the department who supported me with the ERC grant. Because of this supportive culture, I’d like to stay. But I’m worried that if I don’t get the offer I want, I will be too bitter to stay. So yes, I will probably try to leave in that case.

Based on your response to Bryan, I think you’ve correctly identified that this comes down to personal priorities.

My personal experience is that an effective negotiation strategy is to have an offer in hand from another institution. Such a hypothetical institution should be substantially more happy to hire you now that you have a grant, as Buffy notes (assuming it can be taken with you).

To add on to @Ian, in the US, an actual offer in hand often allows the department to dip into a different pool of funds, in particular, the money set aside to recruit new hires.

Thanks, everyone. It seems I need to hit the job market again and get the best offer I can.

If they truly have a policy to make such offers then there is little to do other than inform them. But if it is less formal than that you might start to look elsewhere. If they have just hired someone with similar qualifications then you are probably in a poor position except in a large department.
ERC grants seem to be transferrable between institutions so you would be in a good position in the job market.
Make your case to the decision makers and then choose a path based on what they decide. Hopefully they will continue to support you. Good luck.
